# Passing with Accessors in C#

Tags: c#

I am having a bit of trouble passing variable between forms. I have created a button array and want to pass the button text to the next form. But this is just returning a Null value

In the first form

```
private string staffmem;
    public string Staffmem
    {
        get
        {
            return staffmem;
        }
    }

    public void ClickButton(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        staffmem = btn.Text;
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + staffmem);

        MainScreen ms = new MainScreen();
        ms.Show();
    }
```

and then in the second form

```
        private void MainScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        staffmem = f1.Staffmem;
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new forms in both ends of the communication: when the button is clicked and when you want to retrieve the text -- this results in accessing the `Staffmem` field on a newly created object, which field has not been set to anything, hence the returned `null` value.

In order to be able to retrieve the text, you need to have the *same* `Form1` object to `MainScreen` when it is created:

```
MainScreen ms = new MainScreen(form1);
```

where `form1` is the actual `Form1` object, and store it in `MainScreen` as a member variable

```
// in MainScreen class
private Form1 f1;
```

Then access `Staffmem` on that object on the stored member variable:

```
// in MainScreen_Load()
staffmem = f1.Staffmem;
```

*Note*: depending on your need, you might not want to create a new `MainScreen` from every time the button is clicked either.  In that case (if you already have a created `MainScreen` that you want to communicate with), you need to pass the `MainScreen` object to the `Form1` object as well, when the `Form1` object is created (following the above outlined techniqe)

Comment: Ah right that would make sense. Thanks so much for your help. This would be a common mistake to make I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing anything, you are creating a new Form

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1(); 
staffmem = f1.Staffmem;
```

If the data is to be shared - a really poor way is to make the string static

```
private static string staffmem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a whole new `Form1` - wherein, you wish to use the existing instance.

What you need to do, is define `Staffmem` on your `MainScreen` object, and set it after you create it.

```
MainScreen ms = new MainScreen();
ms.Staffmem = btn.Text;
```

Then, in your MainScreen_Load:
Set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with 2 different objects, first you create a Form1 object and click the button will set the property value on that single object, however in your mainscreen you create a new instance of Form1.

You could pass the form object as a reference to MainScreen itself.

```
MainScreen ms = new MainScreen(this);
ms.Show();
```

And then in the MainScreen class update the constructor to.

```
public MainScreen(Form1 form)
{
    this.form1 = form;
}
```

And keep the reference in a field, like so.

```
private Form1 form1;
```

After this you can do this again,

```
private void MainScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    staffmem = form1.Staffmem;
}
```